# SwingWorker's done method executes even before doInBackground is finished, randomly

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have a piece of `JFrame` code, which stops a `SwingWorker` when it is closed:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 *
 * @author yccheok
 */
public class JavaApplication11 extends JFrame {

    public JavaApplication11() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final Task task = new Task();
        task.execute();
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                if (task != null) {
                    task.cancel(true);
                }
            }           
        }); 
    }

    public class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted in doInBackground");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("-> " + i);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            System.out.println("DONE!!!");
        }        
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication11().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However, randomly, I realize when I close the `JFrame`, `SwingWorker`'s `done` method is executed before `doInBackground` is finished. (You need to execute the above JFrame several times in order to produce the problem)

```
-> 0
-> 1
-> 2
-> 3
-> 4
DONE!!!
interrupted in doInBackground
```

May I know why is it so?

Comment: This is likely a demonstration of a race condition with the stdout

Comment: If MadProgrammer is right, including a time stamp on your sysout calls should show it...  One strategy for tracking this down would be to inlcude the source for Swingworker in your IDE, and set a breakpoint on done and the last step of doInBackgroun... just a thought...

Comment: Isn't it just because done is invoked on the EDT and doInBackground is run on its own thread, so they don't exactly have to come one after the other? And cancel automatically calls done. Also, just add another sleep in the catch block before you print and you'll see it each time.

Comment: *IF* I understand what's going on.  The `Future` which is backing the `SwingWorker` is being cancelled and the `done` method is been called within the context of the same `Thread`.  This means that `done` may being executed before the `Thread` that the `doInBackground` method is running is has been scheduled to run and detect the interrupt...

Comment: standard threading, code (Thread.sleep isnt possible to ....) invoked is by default executed, have to notify and stop those code too

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6826514

Comment: Definitely a threading race condition, because I've gotten both `interrupted in doInBackground` then `DONE!!!` and visa versa like you have.

Answer (score 2):

From Howard's comment, http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6826514 shows this may be a bug.

I've run in to this as well. I tend to put cleanup inside `doInBackground`, if it's order-dependent, and only use `done` for exception handling.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {
    try {
        // ...
    } finally {
        // some cleanup inside 'doInBackground'
        if (isCancelled()) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
    return (Void) null;
}
@Override
protected void done() {
    try {
        get();
    } catch (CancellationException x) {
        // ...
    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        // ...
    } catch (ExecutionException x) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(Remember to use `invokeLater` if you need to update the GUI from `doInBackground`.)

In my case, I had something like this:

- `doInBackground` performing an "open file" routine, creating Swing components periodically and adding them to the GUI.
- On cancellation (via a progress bar dialog with a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button), `done` would remove all the components created during `doInBackground`.

Sometimes these actions would overlap, and `doInBackground` would continue creating components after `done` had performed the wipe. To the user, it would look like pressing <kbd>Cancel</kbd> simply did not work occasionally, except that debug showed that `done` was being called. There was no other explanation, except this behavior of `SwingWorker`.